# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method parseString

Tags: java, android, http, gson, retrofit2

when I use the library with java code to handle the bug of Android 12 and above I got this error when I open chucker to see the Api data
I'm using chucker Library

````
dependencies {
  debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:3.5.2"
  releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2"
}```

```E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ats.jo.royal.patient.dev, PID: 24675
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement; in class Lcom/google/gson/JsonParser;` or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.gson.JsonParser' appears in /data/app/~~baRMxdN_LkhPazLLWRcmsQ==/ats.jo.royal.patient.dev-gxKSg1_qoEJETFmYV5aKCA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.FormatUtils.formatJson(FormatUtils.kt:57)
        at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.data.entity.HttpTransaction.formatBody(HttpTransaction.kt:210)
        at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.data.entity.HttpTransaction.getFormattedRequestBody(HttpTransaction.kt:223)
        at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.ui.transaction.TransactionPayloadFragment$processPayload$2.invokeSuspend(TransactionPayloadFragment.kt:226)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b00062b, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]```
````

Comment: Sounds like incompatible jars (`chuckerteam.chucker` and `gson`)

Comment: can you help me to figure out what is the compatibility ,please?

Comment: Can you check which Gson version is actually in use? The static method was added in Gson 2.8.6: https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html. If you're using an older version for some reason, you need to upgrade it. Not only because of this, but also because there's a vulnerability in versions < 2.8.9 .

Comment: thanks bro I tried and it's solved when we return the gradel

Comment: @MaherAbua-Amireh, do you mind posting your solution as answer to this question? It might help others who have the same problem.

Comment: @Marcono1234
I downgrade the gradle to be ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'```